# Retrieving gerrit link from commit-id

Tags: git, gerrit

Is it possible to retrieve gerrit-link of a particular commit from the gerrit server ?

I am able to retrieve commit-id and author using git log. I want to find a way to retrieve respective gerrit-link for the same from gerrit server so that I can track those respective commits.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Command Line Tools](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-index.html#_server).

With [gerrit query](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html), you can retrieve the link. For example:

```
ssh -p 29418 $username@$gerrithost gerrit query commit:$hash --format=json
# and then parse the json data
```

or

```
ssh -p 29418 $username@$gerrithost gerrit query commit:$hash | grep -E '^  url:'
```

`29418` is the default port. If it's not the case for your gerrit, replace it with the actual number.

With the options of gerrit query, you can retrieve almost everything seen on the page of a specific change, as long as it was pushed to `refs/for/<branch>`.